# How to show a preview of user submitted website in an iframe or localhost?

Tags: javascript, html, django, iframe, localhost

I have been trying to figure out how to display code submitted by a user (html, css, javascript) on my Django website. I can get a single page application to show up in an iframe just fine, such as one html file with css and javascript files linked.

The problem arises when the user has multiple html pages and wants to link between them. I haven't figured out how to allow multiple user-submitted html pages within an iframe. Is it possible to link to another html page with an iframe? Can I set up a localhost environment on my Django application to run the user's website (similar to what CodeAcademy does)?

I have tried writing the user's code to an iframe, which works fine for one html document.

```
let html = "<html><body>My HTML</body></html>";
let doc = document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document;
doc.open();
doc.write(html);
doc.close();
```

I am trying to write multiple html pages to an iframe or set up a localhost environment to allow navigation between pages (index.html, about.html, profile.html, etc)

How can I get this to work?

Comment: an iframe works just like a browser window. if you click on a link in the iframe the link will open in the iframe  unless the link's target attribute specifies otherwise. what have you tried and what exactly is the problem?

Comment: just updated the question with an example

Comment: Hey have you found a way to to it? If yes, could you share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have several sets of HTML strings (for each page).

```
var pages = {
    home: "<html><body>My Home page. <a href='parent.loadPage(\'about\')'>about me</a></body></html>",
    about: "<html><body>My About page. <a href='parent.loadPage(\'Home\')'>Home</a></body></html>"
};
```

Then you'd have a function that loads the code into your iframe

```
function loadPage(page){
    let doc = document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document;
    doc.open();
    doc.write(pages[page]);
    doc.close();
}
```

Then you'd call the function to load the home page...

```
loadPage(page);
```

... and set any links to call that function as well.

```
<a href='parent.loadPage("about")'>
```